# Tensorflow 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, operating-system, opencv

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

DATADIR ="C:/Users/Park/Project/TrainingData"
CATEGORIES = ["doll", "machine", "puzzle"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        print(" Image shape : ", img_array.shape)
        plt.imshow(img_array)
        plt.show()
```

Each folder contains 50 image files in jpg format. The output is up to the second 'machine' folder and the 'puzzle' folder is not output to the third folder. If you change the order of the folder names, the pictures are displayed regardless of the number of images. When I try to output the third folder, I get a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' error.

Comment: To debug, after reading the image, check: `if img_array is None: print(img)`, then try to find the exact path and file in your file explorer if it doesn't exist, you have your bug.

Comment: Where should I put the phrase you mentioned? *phrase = if img_array is None: print(img)

Comment: After reading the image with imread

Comment: I get the same error when I do the following: 
img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        if img_array is None: 
            print(img)
        print(" Image shape : ", img_array.shape)
        plt.imshow(img_array)
        plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

To surface the problem quickly, add

```
if img_array is None:
    print("imread failed on {}".format(img))
```

Comment: It's resolved based on your opinion. Thank you very much. 
The cause was the hidden file 'Photothumb.db'.